# What state/country, given the right, refused to reelect any previous governor/president the most consecutive times?

Tags: election, president, history, governor

In Brazil, mayors, governors and president have the right of one consecutive reelection since 1998. (Such right is being reviewed at Congress right now, but it is not relevant to this question).
As elections to governors and president happen simultaneously each 4 years, there have been 6 elections since then (1998, 2002, 2006, 2010, 2014, 2018).

The Rio Grande do Sul state (with ~11 million people) is the only one that never reelected its governor. As a comparison, similar to the US, the last 3 presidents with this opportunity were reelected (Fernando Henrique Cardoso in 1998, Lula da Silva in 2006, and Dilma Rousseff in 2014).

So, is there another similar experience around the world (i.e., a state or country that, given the right, refused to reelect its previous governor or president 6 or more consecutive times)?

Comment: IMHO, a far more interesting question is, what's so special about Rio Grande do Sul compared to the rest of Brazil which causes this differene?

Comment: What do you mean by “by most consecutive time”? Which countries have restrictions like Brazil's? Which countries have no restrictions? Whether some countries have even stricter restrictions?

Comment: @Relaxed On your 1st question: by most consecutive time I mean the number of elections in a row the electorate refuses to reelect the previous holder. In the example of Rio Grande do Sul it was 5 times.

On 2nd and 3rd questions: see [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_term_limits).

On your 4th question, it is controversial. In favor to reelection are to give opportunity to complete a cycle of well-doing and not restrict liberty to the elector; against are the sense of natural privilege to the current holder and the risk of abuse of political machine.

Comment: I tried to reformulate your question, let me know if that's OK.

Comment: Kind of cheating but elective monarchies would qualify: the leader is only elected once, never reelected, that could even be the very definition of an elective monarchy. It's not very common but [there are still several today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elective_monarchy) and you could perhaps add the Vatican to the list.

Comment: Another non-answer: Switzerland. The presidency is held each year by someone different. Some people have served twice but never twice in a row. But they remain members of the federal council (i.e. the government) and are in fact virtually always reelected to the council.

Comment: @Relaxed You didn't tried to reformulate my question. You achieved it! I don't understand why the system did not asked me confirmation :/
Anyway, I liked most your first correction. Upon it, I included the important detail: I am asking what country or state did not reelected, **given the right** to do so...
If Switzerland does not allow it (I don't know, does it?) or of course Vatican, that does not count. BTW, my first writing to this question were on the way "What is the most disappointed/dissatisfied state/country...?"

Comment: You rolled back my suggestion, I will let you look for a better way to put it but “them” is simply a grammar mistake, it makes no sense in the context and your question is still extremely unclear.

Comment: @Relaxed You are right. I just missed that "them", of course it is "then", thanks :)

Is the general sense of the question still unclear? I am trying to ask what other places on earth the people refuses more times to reelect its previous holder, **given the right** to do so.

Comment: @curiouser With your explanations, I understood your question but the way you put it was very confusing, which is why I offered another version.

Comment: @user4012 I created [this question inspired by your comment](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/why-has-rio-grande-do-sul-state-brazil-never-reelected-its-governor).

Comment: @curiouser I would rather hope you would reformulate your question, I can see that English is not your first language and what you are getting at is difficult to express clearly and concisely but at the moment your last sentence barely makes sense. Reading the comments should not be necessary to understand what you mean!

Comment: @Relaxed: Thanks for understanding. I just tried it again, please edit if you can improve that :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is a trivia question tangental to politics not really about politics or policies.

Comment: @Chad I understand why it can be seen as a trivia question, but it is not. Right now, Brazilian Congress is about to eliminate the re-election right. On the basis that it gives an unbalanced privilege to the actual holder of the executive power. This same kind of argument can  repeat itself around the world, right?
So, I really want to know how much experiences like this replicates. I.e. an unbalanced favor towards _fresh candidates_.

Comment: Then ask that question... that is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been some time, but this occurred in the State that I live in. [Michigan had six consecutive Governors that lost reelection (1931-1943)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_governors_of_Michigan), if you include a Governor who passed away with the Lieutenant Governor running, and losing reelection.

1. Wilber M. Bruckner was elected in 1930, serving from January 1, 1931 to January 1, 1933. He lost reelection to William Comstock.
2. William Comstock was elected in 1932, defeating incumbent Wilber M. Bruckner, serving from January 1, 1933 to January 1, 1935. He lost reelection to Frank Fitzgerald.
3. Frank Fitzgerald was elected in 1934, defeating incumbent William Comstock, serving from January 1, 1935 to January 1, 1937. He lost reelection to Frank Murphy.
4. Frank Murphy was elected in 1936, defeating incumbent Frank Fitzgerald, serving from January 1, 1937 to January 1, 1939. He lost reelection to the preceding Governor Frank Fitzgerald.
5. Frank Fitzgerald was elected in 1938, defeating incumbent Frank Murphy, serving from January 1, 1939 until his death on March 16, 1939. He was succeeded by his Lieutenant Governor Luren Dickinson, who served until January 1, 1941. Governor Dickinson ran for election and was defeated by Murray Van Wagoner.
6. Murray Van Wagoner was elected in 1940, defeating incumbent Luren Dickinson, serving from January 1, 1941 to January 1, 1943. He lost reelection to Harry Kelly, who went on to serve two consecutive terms.

Comment: Welcome, and great answer! It reminded me to update the question with the results from 2018 Brazilian general elections. So it is currently a tie and I accepted your answer! If the electoral calendar is maintained we will see 2022 if the draw remains or Rio Grande do Sul electors refuses the incumbent a reelection for the seventh consecutive time ;)

Comment: I look forward to it ;)

Answer (score 4):

The Governor of the Commonwealth of Virginia is [constitutionally prohibited](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/constitution/article5/section1/) from serving consecutive terms. The governor may be re-elected after an intervening term, but only [two governors have done so since 1830](https://www.encyclopediavirginia.org/governors_of_virginia):

- William Smith served as a Democrat from 1846 to 1849 and again from 1864 to 1865. There were two state governments during the Civil War; Smith served under the Confederacy.
- Mills Edwin Godwin, Jr. served as a Democrat from 1966 to 1970 and as a Republican from 1974 to 1978.

Between 1865 and 1966, there were 26 consecutive governors who were not re-elected.

Since 1978, there have been 11 consecutive governors who have not been re-elected.